# Why does my AS3 Video scrubber work in Preview and FP10 but not when published to Air?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, air

I have coded an as3 class in Flash Pro to make an flv video pan backwards and forwards as the user drags the mouse left and right over the video sprite. (The video is an orbit of a building so the effect is to spin the building around with the mouse). The video has been loaded to a DisplayObject using Greensock's LoaderMax.

It all works fine in Flash Player 10 and the preview, but won't pan when published to Air 2 for desktop on windows. Video just jumps to the final position on mouseUp. Would this most likely be a limitation of Air? if so, why does the preview work? Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Air 2? That's like... archaic. Any particular reason why you are using it? (I am not saying that's the problem - you should provide your relevant code)

Comment: Yeah, fair point. I've been learning AS3 for the last few months on Flash Pro CS5.0 and just started exporting to AIR and that's the highest cs5 offers. Bit the bullet yesterday and upgraded to CC. Now my code doesn't even work in Flash Player 10 so bit more research required, and this question is redundant. Btw, I've been using this functionality on my 15 year old Adobe Director, and it just works! Is this progress??

Comment: I will strip the code back to basics and submit that for more advice if I don't get it working. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You should remember that there is no need for flash cc. You can just download the air sdk and use it with any IDE you want for free. Of course if you require some animation-tool, flash cc is good enough. ;)